# Grass Seeds to throw- AZ High Desert

Tags: ground-cover

Is there a ground cover seed or seed mix that I can throw out around my yard during monsoon season that will take root and possibly displace the weeds that spring up after/during the rains?

Comment: I have no problems keeping up watering through out the year.

Answer (score 3):

Found a perfect list for you.  Make sure you do not over water once established!  If you want to diminish weeds the higher the ground cover the better to shade seed.  Best to choose one or two, maybe three and make sweeps of masses.  Too many species won't look very professional.  Lawns look great because they appear as a uniform entity. [low water ground cover plants for Arizona](http://www.amwua.org/groundcovers.html)